# Add a 'time' dimension to xarray Dataset and assign coordinates from another Dataset to it

Tags: numpy, python-xarray

I have a Dataset object (imported from a netCDF file through `xarray.open_dataset`) named `ds`. It contains a variable named `variable1` and `latitude` and `longitude` dimensions.

```
>>>ds
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (latitude: 681, longitude: 841)
Coordinates:
  * latitude   (latitude) float64 -10.0 -10.05 -10.1 ... -43.9 -43.95 -44.0
  * longitude  (longitude) float64 112.0 112.0 112.1 112.2 ... 153.9 153.9 154.0
Data variables:
    variable1     (latitude, longitude) float32 ...
```

I have a `time` DataArray object with coordinates from `2017-01-01` to `2017-13-31`.

```
>>>times = pd.date_range("2017/01/01","2018/01/01",freq='D',closed='left')
>>>time_da = xr.DataArray(times, [('time', times)])
>>>time_da
<xarray.DataArray (time: 365)>
array(['2017-01-01T00:00:00.000000000', '2017-01-02T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-01-03T00:00:00.000000000', ..., '2017-12-29T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-12-30T00:00:00.000000000', '2017-12-31T00:00:00.000000000'],
      dtype='datetime64[ns]')
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2017-01-01 2017-01-02 ... 2017-12-31
```

I would like to add a new dimension called `time` and assign the coordinates from `time_da` to it so that the new Dataset `ds2` will look like:

```
>>>ds2
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (latitude: 681, longitude: 841, time: 365)
Coordinates:
  * longitude  (longitude) float64 112.0 112.0 112.1 112.2 ... 153.9 153.9 154.0
  * latitude   (latitude) float64 -10.0 -10.05 -10.1 ... -43.9 -43.95 -44.0
  * time       (time) datetime64[ns] 2017-01-01 2017-01-02 ... 2017-12-31
Data variables:
    sm_pct     (time, latitude, longitude) float32 nan nan nan ... nan nan nan
```

This means the original DataArray [latitude, longitude] will be duplicated by 365 times across the the entire time period in the `time` dimension.

I tried to use `ds.expand_dims` to create `time` dimension and assign `time_da` to it but this didn't work. The error was:

```
>>> ds2 = ds.expand_dims(dim='time', axis=0)
>>> ds2.coords['time'] = ('time',time_da)
ValueError: conflicting sizes for dimension 'time': length 1 on <this-array> and length 730 on 'time'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an appropriate usage of `expand_dims` for you:

```
>>> dst = ds.expand_dims(time=time_da)
>>> dst
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (latitude: 681, longitude: 841, time: 365)
Coordinates:
  * time       (time) datetime64[ns] 2017-01-01 2017-01-02 ... 2017-12-31
  * latitude   (latitude) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 ... 674 675 676 677 678 679 680
  * longitude  (longitude) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 ... 834 835 836 837 838 839 840
Data variables:
    variable   (time, latitude, longitude) float64 0.03968 2.156 ... -1.752
```

Checking that `variable` is the same at each timestep:

```
>>> np.all(np.diff(dst["variable"], axis=0) == 0)
True
```